# Drag and Dropping Rows between two separate QTableWidgets

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

*Background:*

I have two separate `QTableWidget`s on my `Main Window`. Both of which are dynamically added in python. I have implemented pyqt code, which can be found  under three_pineapples solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227885/drag-and-drop-rows-within-qtablewidget).

*My Problem*

I want to be able to drag and drop table rows from one table, to another. For example:

If I attempt to drag Item B from the **Left Table** into the **Right Table**

[image: Example pt. 1]

This would be the outcome

[image: Example pt. 2]

Any suggestions on how to get this desired behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the @three_pineapples' code, didn't understand a half and deleted that half. Works with multiple row selection.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class TableWidgetDragRows(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        # self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

        self.last_drop_row = None

    # Override this method to get the correct row index for insertion
    def dropMimeData(self, row, col, mimeData, action):
        self.last_drop_row = row
        return True


    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # The QTableWidget from which selected rows will be moved
        sender = event.source()

        # Default dropEvent method fires dropMimeData with appropriate parameters (we're interested in the row index).
        super().dropEvent(event)
        # Now we know where to insert selected row(s)
        dropRow = self.last_drop_row

        selectedRows = sender.getselectedRowsFast()

        # Allocate space for transfer
        for _ in selectedRows:
            self.insertRow(dropRow)

        # if sender == receiver (self), after creating new empty rows selected rows might change their locations
        sel_rows_offsets = [0 if self != sender or srow < dropRow else len(selectedRows) for srow in selectedRows]
        selectedRows = [row + offset for row, offset in zip(selectedRows, sel_rows_offsets)]

        # copy content of selected rows into empty ones
        for i, srow in enumerate(selectedRows):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                item = sender.item(srow, j)
                if item:
                    source = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                    self.setItem(dropRow + i, j, source)

        # delete selected rows
        for srow in reversed(selectedRows):
            sender.removeRow(srow)

        event.accept()


    def getselectedRowsFast(self):
        selectedRows = []
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            if item.row() not in selectedRows:
                selectedRows.append(item.row())
        selectedRows.sort()
        return selectedRows


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.table_widgets = []
        for _ in range(3):
            tw = TableWidgetDragRows()
            tw.setColumnCount(2)
            tw.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Colour', 'Model'])

            self.table_widgets.append(tw)
            layout.addWidget(tw)

        filled_widget = self.table_widgets[0]
        items = [('Red', 'Toyota'), ('Blue', 'RV'), ('Green', 'Beetle')]
        for i, (colour, model) in enumerate(items):
            c = QTableWidgetItem(colour)
            m = QTableWidgetItem(model)

            filled_widget.insertRow(filled_widget.rowCount())
            filled_widget.setItem(i, 0, c)
            filled_widget.setItem(i, 1, m)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This does seem to work, however may I suggest you add a check before creating and setting the `QTableWidgetItem`. This check will simply read: `if(sender.item(srow,j) is not None):` 
Otherwise if one cell of the row is empty their is major data loss upon drop. Thanks for your answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @sudobangbang thanks for your remark. I overlooked this problem, it occurs with python 2, which uses the old PyQt API v1 by default. The check has been added.